# Bash: Is it possible to set an alias with wildcard

Tags: bash

Is it possible to include a wildcard in an alias, like:

```
alias *="echo triggered"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. This would only trigger for a literal asterisk.

If you want to override most commands, you can botch `PATH` and use `command_not_found_handle`:

```
$ PATH=/invalid
$ command_not_found_handle() { echo "triggered"; }
$ man ls
triggered
$ firefox
triggered
$ asdfasdfasdf
triggered
```

This will not apply to aliases, builtins, or when running commands with full path.